# Программный доступ к элементам DataTemplate в ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Доброе утро!

Имеется следующая разметка:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding /*коллекция_данных*/}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbxTable, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
             <CheckBox x:Name="cbxDays" />
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding /*дочерняя_коллекция*/}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbxDays, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}">
                  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <Grid />
                        </DataTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              </ItemsControl>
          </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
```

То есть: N-уровневая коллекция данных, для нее - N вложенных `ItemsControl`. Так как Visibility у дочерних `ItemsControl`'ов через binding зависит от свойства `IsChecked` `CheckBox`'а, расположенного на уровне выше, для логики работы необходимо программное изменение свойства IsChecked.

Реализовано следующим образом:

```
ContentPresenter c = /*parent ItemsControl*/.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(/*parent ItemsControl*/.Items[/*необходимый индекс из модели*/]) as ContentPresenter;
Grid grid = c.ContentTemplate.LoadContent() as Grid;
CheckBox cbDays = FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(grid).FirstOrDefault();
cbDays.IsChecked = true;
```

При этом в найденном `Grid` присутствуют по VisualTree все элементы, но:

1. Дочерний `ItemsControl` содержит 0 элементов (хотя в модели они есть)
2. Программное изменение свойства `IsChecked` у найденного `CheckBox` не работает.

При этом при нажатии на `CheckBox` в UI все работает корректно.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Не, что-то вы делаете не то. Если вы хотите управлять видимостью частей интерфейса из бизнес-логики, то и видимость вам нужно биндить не на чекбокс, а на свойство вью-модели. Расскажите свою настоящую задачу.